# C# NullReferenceException on Win32_PhysicalMemory

Tags: c#, wmi

I have the following struct;

```
static Memory memory;

  public struct Memory
  {
      public string Name;
      public string Manufacturer;
      public string MemoryType ;
      public string Speed;
      public string DeviceLocator;
      public string Capacity;
      public string OtherInfo;
  };
```

I can obtain everything but the following:

```
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");
         ManagementObjectCollection myobject = searcher.Get();
             foreach (ManagementObject item in myobject)
             {
                memory.OtherInfo = item["OtherIdentifyingInfo"].ToString();
             }
```

When i try to do the above, i get:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Do i have to somehow create an instance of  `item["OtherIdentifyingInfo"]`?

Comment: @SLaks I went ahead and added the other information, sorry about that.

Comment: WMI just return null for OtherIdentifyingInfo, does this make sense? there is no OtherIdentifyingInfo, you should check if it is null before tostring

Comment: @ArsenMkrt seriously? what's the purpose of the property then? That's confusing to have a property that always returns Null? But thank you.

Comment: WMI properties are quite often null.  You have to test for that before you try to use ToString().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OtherIdentifyingInfo**

Data type: string
Access type: Read-only
Additional data, beyond asset tag information, that can be used to identify a physical element. One example is bar code data associated with an element that also has an asset tag. If only bar code data is available and unique or able to be used as an element key, this property is be NULL and the bar code data is used as the class key in the tag property. This property is inherited from CIM_PhysicalElement.

You need to Check if the value is Null before you pass to string.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `null` check will fix the error, but it looks like `Win32_PhysicalMemory` does not use `OtherIdentifyingInfo`

```
memory = new Memory();
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");
ManagementObjectCollection myobject = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject item in myobject)
{
    if (item["OtherIdentifyingInfo"] != null)
       memory.OtherInfo = item["OtherIdentifyingInfo"].ToString();
}
```